# Adding back in missing controls to windows form control

Tags: vb.net

I have received a project from a client and in this project, it contains some custom controls in the toolbox (for those wondering, this is a vb.net application WFC).

One of the forms is unable to load because I decided to upload this project to TFS and when it did that, some of the references were lost. One of those references was the custom controls.

From what I can tell, the contorl is a text box.

Now, I should note that I do have a copy of the files where the form is able to load. However, this copy is not connected to the TFS.

After some analysis on on working form, I have concluded that the custom control is a simple text box. I decided to attempt to add this custom control into the tfs version by replicating the directory structure within the toolbox.

I added in a new label, named it the same as the working version, copied the text box control to the new label, and renamed it to the control that is in the working version.

I closed the form and reopened it only to discover that it did not work, I am still getting the same error that the reference could not be found.

So now, I am wondering, is there a way that I can manually add in control references to the visual studio project so that the form is able to build properly?

Edit:

Hey all, so it looks like this issue was somehow related to another issue that I was having where Visual studio was unable to load a dll file from the internet. I had to select unblock from the properties. After that, I can now load the form and it looks like all controls are available.

Comment: Anything specific in the error that might help? Post the full error message?

Comment: Hey all, so it looks like this issue was somehow related to another issue that I was having where Visual studio was unable to load a dll file from the internet. I had to select unblock from the properties. After that, I can now load the form and it looks like all controls are available.